# Grading system: Why A-F and not E?

Tags: united-states, grades

Why do we use F for failing on an otherwise arbitrary alphabetic grading scale? Isn't E just as meaningful for failing as A is for excellent?

I'm more interested in a response on the history of how the current scale came to be.

(Edit: prompted from the comments below, I am asking about this situation within the context of the American grading system.)

Comment: This [linked document](http://academics.holycross.edu/files/Education/schneider/Making_the_Grade_JCS_pre-pub.pdf) might be of interest

Comment: I taught at a high school that used grades A-E, with E being a failing grade.  I would suggest that the obvious reason for using F is because it stands for "Fail."

Comment: @PeterJansson That is a great resource on the history but from what I read it is still missing the topic of interest, why F instead of E?

Comment: At our university, E is the failing grade.

Comment: As Suresh indicates in his answer, the grading scale varies with locale; some regions do use A-E.

Comment: Indeed, this is by no means universal.  At my undergraduate university in New Zealand, the grades were A-D with D being a fail (there were also + and - versions of every grade including D).  At my PhD university in the UK, there were no letter grades.

Comment: Okay, maybe I should have more specifically asked "Why, in the United States (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_grading_in_the_United_States), is the letter F used rather than the logical succession E? It's been suggested that F represents the first letter of Failing, but neither A, B, C, or D have these connections to specific words.

Comment: My university *is* in the US :)

Comment: I heard once that "E" was historically associated with "excellent", in the sense more than was even required and was a grade better than "A". On the other hand, I was never graded with letter-grades in my life, and I can't quote a reliable source on this so I might be wrong.

Comment: @penelope:  That's interesting.  In the current NZ school system E is the best grade and stands for excellent.  I think the next is M for 'merit' and then A for 'achieved'.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm more surprised by the choice of letters over numbers itself.

Comment: I don't know the history of the US system (in the UK 'E' is generally used), but if the non-usage has progressed from elementary/high school upwards, one might conjecture that it's to prevent students being able to easily convert an 'F' into an 'E' on a report card.

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre agreed! It makes no sense, as one already has to count points anyhow, just give a ratio of acquired pts/ total available pts.

Comment: @PeterJansson referenced a great article. [This one](http://bethune.yorku.ca/files/2013/09/2014-Schinske-Tanner-Teaching-more-by-grading-less-or-differently-.pdf) also discusses the history of grades in the US. Basically, there was an E (A-F) but it was dropped and F retained (likely because it's normal mental connection the Fail).

Comment: Sometimes we say "E for effort", meaning good try, still fail. I don't think it's official anywhere.

Comment: Just a guess: some courses are on a Pass (P) or Fail (F) system. You may want to have the same letter for failure in the two systems.

Comment: [Europe has E for barely passed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECTS_grading_scale).

Comment: The relevant material in the article linked by PeterJansson seems to be at pp. 25-26, but it only gives the time frame, not the process by which ABCDF was chosen.

Comment: The Schinske article linked to by earthlink says: 'While it is unclear exactly when and why "E" grades disappeared from the letter grade scale, it seems possible that this push to use fewer categories resulted in an "A"--"F" scale with no "E" ("F" being retained, since it so clearly stood for "fail"). Others have conjectured that "E" was removed so students would not assume "E" stood for "excel- lent," but whatever the reason, "E's" apparently disappeared by the 1930s (Palmer, 2010).'

Answer (score 7):

I think, and this is really only conjecture since I don't know the history, is the potential conflict with the ESNU system where E stands for excellent. The ESNU was (and potentially still is) used in US based elementary education.

Answer (score 5):

My US high school had a grading scheme where A-D were all passing grades, and E and F were both failing grades (E is between 50 and 60, F is less than 50).  I believe the difference was that an E class could be retaken, whereas an F could not.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems we have trouble finding a true history of the A-F my guess would be the following. Many scales rely oon an odd number scale because then something can be in the middle. It is also then possible to think of C as the center of a normal distribution, if that is how grades should be distributed. We used to have a grading system from 1-5 with no intermdiate steps in schools in Sweden where 3 was considered an ok grade and 1 and 2 were poor. There was also a fail whioch was a dash instead of a number.

By accident or by construction, F became Fail. It is possible that a five grade scale was chosen to make F Fail but my guess is that it was more a fotunate coincidence rather than deliberate choice.